# NgTemplateOutlet performance problems

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

> I want to create a generic list using angular 2, which gets a
>   component as it's item and implements list behavior using that item.

```
    @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'generic-list',
    template:  `
         <md-nav-list>
     <generic-content *ngFor="let item of genericList" (click)="emitClickEvent(item)"
        [item-data]="item"
        [template-reference]="templateReference">
    </generic-content>
</md-nav-list>
    `,
    styles:[`
        md-nav-list {
            padding-top: 8px;
        }
    `]
})
export class GenericListComponent {
    @Input('generic-list') genericList: Array<Object>;
    @ContentChild('templateReference') templateReference: TemplateRef<ITemplate>;

    @Output('on-select') onSelectEmitter: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

    emitClickEvent(item){
        this.onSelectEmitter.emit(item)
    }
}
```

> This is the generic list and this is my content

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'generic-content',
    template: `
    <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateReference" [ngOutletContext]="{ $implicit: itemData }"></template>
    `
})
export class GenericContentComponent {
    @Input('item-data') itemData: Object;
    @Input('template-reference') templateReference: TemplateRef<ITemplate>;
}

export interface ITemplate {
    itemData: Object;
    context: any;
}
```

> Everything works fine but now I will use an item to fill the list

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'employee-item',
    template:
    `
    <div *ngIf="itemData" class="employee-item" [class.selected]="itemData.selected">
    <div class="employee-name">
        {{itemData.EMPLOYEE_ID}}
    </div>
    <div class="employee-number">
        {{itemData.PAYROLL_EMPL_NO}}
    </div>
</div>
    `,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native,
    styleUrls: ['./employee-item.component.css']
})

export class EmployeeItemComponent {
    @Input() itemData: Employee;
}

export class Employee {
    employeeId: number;
    employeeName: string;
}
```

> And put everything inside a component

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'employee-list',
    template: `
    <generic-list class="employee-list" [generic-list]="emplyeeList" [style.width]="emplyeeList && emplyeeList.length === 0 ? '0px' : 'auto'" (on-select)="employeeSelect($event)">
    <template #templateReference let-itemData>
        <employee-item [itemData]="itemData"></employee-item>
    </template>
    </generic-list>
    `,
    styles: [
        '.employee-list {transition: width ease-in-out;}'
    ]
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('employee-list') emplyeeList: Array<Object>;
    @Output('on-employee-select') employeeSelectEmitter: EventEmitter<Object> = new EventEmitter<Object>();

    private selectedEmployee;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    employeeSelect($event) {
        if (!$event) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.selectedEmployee && this.selectedEmployee.selected) {
            this.selectedEmployee.selected = false;
        }

        this.selectedEmployee = $event;
        this.selectedEmployee.selected = true;

        this.employeeSelectEmitter.emit($event);
    }
}
```

> The problem is that the hole thing is very slow it takes  like 5 or 6
>   seconds to render the entire list. Is this a problem with angular ? Or
>   I do something wrong with the references

Comment: Also I should mention that I'm Angular 2 RC.5. If is a RC.5 problem I will update to 2.0 final

Comment: How many items? You could try if `*ngFor` with `ngForTemplate` is faster. I don't think there was much related change since RC.5 but I could miss something. Upgrading would be a good idea anyway. Have you also checked performance with AoT and prodMode instead of devMode?

Comment: 3 items, and it slows over time, first render 2 seconds, I empty the list and fill it agains second render 5 seconds, I think I tried 7 times this and the last time took like 9 seconds

Comment: Sounds extreme. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: We can try temviewer the project is big and I see that plunker has only ng2 beta.01

Comment: Sorry, I'm not interested in seeing a big project. It needs to be a reduced project that contains only what is required to reproduce the issue. If you use the "new" button in Plunker editor and then > Angular > 2.0.x you get a 2.0 final template.

Comment: Ok I will try to do that

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/TbxsQprYYkTijFCzlDeu?p=preview
This is the exact configuration but it seems on plunker is not reproducing

Comment: Doesn't look slow. How to reproduce?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124512/discussion-between-nicu-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was `ViewEncapsulation.Native` since I'm also using
>   angular 2 material and sass. each item had a lot of custom styles
>   which are appended to the html. The first solution is to change to
>   `ViewEncapsulation.None`.